# Arduino Uno to Raspberry Pi output required as a float but get b'VALUE\r\n'

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno

I have gone through a few questions that are similar to mine but I can't see one which gives a solid solution for me (also I am fairly new to all of this). I have connected an Arduino Uno with a Raspberry Pi using a USB cable, so that I can read values from the Arduino using the serial connection. Everything seems to be connected ok, but I can't seem to get a float value from the values being read over the serial connection. The output within python is in the form:

b'VALUE\r\n' (where VALUE is the number I require)

which I think is a Bytes value? I retrieved the Arduino sketch from an example online so I am pretty sure that that is fine, and it outputs the correct values to the serial monitor in the Arduino program. The python code I am using is:

```
    import serial
    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/tty/ACM0",9600)
    ser.baudrate = 9600

    while True:
        read_ser = ser.readline().strip.decode("utf-8")
        #read_ser = float(ser.readline().strip())
        #read_ser = ser.readline().strip()
        #read_ser = ser_readline()
        print(read_ser)
```

The first attempt at reading with the decode gives the error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte

The second: 
Reads a few values and then says:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'0.0\xfd05025'
(I did read somewhere that this may be due to the delay time in the arduino sketch? I currently have this as 1ms, is this too low?)

The third and fourth do produce the values but with the excess characters/ as a string.

Many thanks!
P.S. The Arduino Code:

```
#define trigPin 11
#define echoPin 12

float duration, distance;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  // Write a pulse to the HC-SR04 Trigger Pin

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  // Measure the response from the HC-SR04 Echo Pin

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // Determine distance from duration
  // Use 343 metres per second as speed of sound

  distance = ((duration / 2) * 0.0343)/100;

  // Send results to Serial Monitor
  Serial.println(distance,5);
  delay(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that I use for serial communication between Raspberry and Arduino is:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

while True:
    readSerial = ser.readline()
    print readSerial
```

Note that this code is in Python 2.7 and you'll have to make minor changes to use it in Python 3.x. Also make sure you have the correct serial port in Raspberry as mine is always USB0(I think ACM is reserved but I'm probably wrong here).

Moreover, if there is a delay in the Arduino sketch, it's better to add it in the Raspberry code as well(try a delay slightly greater than the one in Arduino).

Update: The Arduino code I used is as follows:

```
float duration = 10;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  duration = duration + 1;
  float distance = ((duration / 2) * 0.0343)/100;
  Serial.println(distance,5);
  delay(1);
}
```

I used this code because I didn't have UltraSonic sensor at my disposal, but this works the same.

Here is the output in RaspberryPi:
[image]

I think you should check the format of your serial port and see if the port is correct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I think perhaps I have been unclear with what my issue is? I can obtain the serial output from the Arduino on the Raspberry Pi, (so I think that means I have the correct serial port?). My issue is that I can't get the float value or any useable value from the output as it is in the Bytes format?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your Arduino part of the code so that I can get an idea of what kind of a code we're dealing with?

Comment: Sure, I've added it into the question.